# mySQL - Regexp or LIKE in multiple search?

Tags: php, mysql

This script searches multiple keywords.

```
SELECT ID,SURNAME FROM people where name='john' 
and SURNAME REGEXP 'search1|search2|search3' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

However, I have heard that regexp has lower performance and never use indexes. Is there a better/faster way to do the same ?

Comment: That depends, are you looking for a partial match or an exact match ? E.G. `SURNAME = 'search1'` or `SURNAME LIKE '%search1%'` ?

Comment: partial. Exact is not needed

Answer (score 1):

it depends a lot on the size of your dataset and the surname column. it also depends on how many surnames you end up including in your search.

I suggest testing it with a few different search terms and seeing if this is faster:

```
SELECT ID,SURNAME FROM people where name='john' 
and (SURNAME LIKE '%search1%' OR SURNAME LIKE '%search2%' OR SURNAME LIKE '%search3%') 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

note that if your search only needs a wildcard at the end, you can use 'search1%' instead of '%search1%' which should be faster